# How to render data from ona.io in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json, ajax, open-data-kit

I want to consume data from ona.io into a leaflet map on another server. I guess using the api with the format: jsonp, might be a way. I'm not sure how to use e.g. leaflet-ajax to parse the data into something useful. Since I'm not a programmer I having hard times to figure it out.

I want however data from following address:

https://ona.io/api/v1/data?owner=Kajakplatser 
ona.io/api/v1/data/119605?format=jsonp

into this map as a layer:

https://kajakplatser.se/karta

Is there someone out there having done this or done it in some similar/different way that want to share their ideas?